# How do you store undefined number of things in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Say, we have data of person that have some possessions. The person can have nothing or have anything. What is the proper way to store data like this?

As far as I know, MySQL doesn't provide a way to store array as a data type. If it does, maybe it will be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    possessions ARRAY NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Create a linking table and store each possessions of the person into that table linked with `id`

Comment: Doesn't it means I have to define how much tables (or columns) to store the data? But, my questions is about creating table that we don't know how many columns we will insert to.

Comment: You use EAV design to store undefined number of undefined "things". Google it to see what it is, you don't get it out of the box.

Comment: The best and standard way to do this is to use another table, which will be linked to the main table through ID.

But if you are not sure about the number of columns that needs to be created in the linked table, you can specify the possessions column as `VARCHAR`, which will be `comma` separated or use some other character to separate the possessions.

Comment: @Saagar, 'comma separated'. No. Bad. OP to clarify the others suggestion: two tables, person and possessions. And person will just have id and name, which possessions will have id (which will allow you to link to JOIN and thus link to the person table, possibly a type varchar (or enum if you have a set number of types of possessions) column (to further define the type of possession), and the thing column, also varchar (the possession - car, pen, whatever). Each insert into thing table will list the id, type and possession, one row. So SELECT * from thing where id=10125 will list all.

Comment: @user3741598 my first suggestion is to use another table, but OP says he is unsure of how many possessions a person can have - so unsure about how many columns in the linked table.

Comment: EAV designs ("comma separated" columns) can work in limited circumstances, but only use them in you absolutely know what you are doing. They are very difficult to query and to join to, so mostly you should just use separate tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you would be looking for is three tables (or two if each possession can only be owned by one person).

1. Table Person has PersonId (INT PK Identifier) and PersonName (along
   with any other person attributes)
2. Table Possession has PossessionId
   (INT PK Identifier) and PossessionName (along with any other
   possession attributes)
3. Table PersonPossession has PersonId and
   PossessionId representing that the person has that possession.

This is a fairly simple design for an m:n relationship (i.e. a person has some number (possibly 0) of possessions, and possessions have some number of "owners")

If each possession can only be owned by a single person you can go down to two tables by eliminating table PersonPossession and just having PersonId being a column of the Possessions table